# How to prove If $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{a_{n}}^3 = a^{3}, \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_{n} = a$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I do not know if $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{a_{n}}^3 = a^{3}$ , $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_{n} = a$

Can you help me?

Comment: The title and the question body do not seem to match. I think this was an ambiguity introduced while editing.

Comment: Hint: limit of a product is product of the limitd

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may exploit
$$
a_n^3-a^3=(a_n-a)(a_n^2+aa_n+a^2).
$$

Comment: Thank you for answering Can you explain it specifically?

Comment: What can be said about the latter factor above?

Comment: i think it is bounded

Comment: We have $a_n^2+aa_n+a^2\ge\frac34 a^2$.Two cases: $a\ne0$, $a=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the function $c\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $c(x)=\sqrt[3]x$ is continuous,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}^3=a^3\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=a.$$

Comment: The OP wants the reverse implication.

Comment: @egreg I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that no-one talked about composition of limits...

Let $g:x\mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$. This maps is continuous in $a^3$, so you can compose limits and $\displaystyle g(\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n^3)=\lim_{n\to \infty}(g(a_n^3))$, that is $g(a^3)=a=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

As $\lim(a_n)^3=a^3$ by definition of limit there exists ε>0 such that ${\vert (a_n)^3-a^3\vert}$<ε    =>${\vert ((a_n)-a)((a_n)^2+a_na+a^2)\vert}<ε$ =>  ${\vert {a_n-a}\vert}{\vert (a_n)^2+a_na+a^2\vert}<ε$ so ${\vert {a_n-a}\vert}$≤${\vert {a_n-a}\vert}$ ${ {\vert {(a_n)^2+a_na+a^2}\vert}}$ <ε so ${\vert a_n-a\vert}<ε$ so ${lima_n}=a$

Comment: The factor $\vert a_n^2+a_na+a^2\vert$ could be quite small. Particularly if $a$ and $a_n$ are both close to zero. So even though $|(a-a_n)|\cdot|a_n^2+a_na+a^2|$ is $<\varepsilon$, it is not at all clear that $|a-a_n|<\varepsilon$. You need something extra. Particularly when $a=0$.

Comment: Here ε is however small and this is the definition of limit if lim(a)=b then |a-b|<ε for ε>0(however small)

Comment: But you didn't prove that $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$ for all large enough $n$. The error is in thinking that
$$|a_n-a|\le |a_n-a|\cdot |a_n^2+aa_n+a^2|.$$ This is false, when the latter factor is $<1$. You can recover whenever you can bound that latter factor away from zero. Do you see how? But when $a=0$ you cannot bound it like that, and you need a totally different argument.

Comment: When a=0 $a_n$≤$a_n^3$<ε hence a_n<ε

Comment: No. When $0<a_n<1$ you have $a_n^3<a_n$. Practice your number sense!